# How to compile maven/flex project without any *.mxml file?

Tags: actionscript-3, maven-2, flex4

Is there any way how to compile maven/flex project which does not contain any *.mxml?
The flex project contains ActionScript classes only (i.e. "src/flex" directory contains *.as files only). My pom.xml is here:

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>test</name>
<packaging>swf</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/flex</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.0.18623</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.18623</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flexunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexunit</artifactId>
        <version>0.85</version>
        <type>swc</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

"mvn package -e" throws this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.8:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) on project test: Source file not expecified and no default found! -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.8:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) on project q-integra-scorecard-ldservice: Source file not expecified and no default found!
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this inside <plugin>, where "Main.as" is your class:

```
<configuration>
    <sourceFile>Main.as</sourceFile>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't have any primary source files (it was a SWC full of interface classes like ISessionProxy.as).

So I had to do two things to get this working:

1) reference my source directory (under the build tag):

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
```

2) follow the advice I found [on this mail group](http://markmail.org/message/dbn5h6l5uhi7klhk#query%3a+page:1+mid:7jg3rjw46eisxmxe+state%3aresults) and [the FlexMojos Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos/msg/808bd00929e8c79e?hl=en):

> "...just remove all dependencies on your pom, because those dependencies
>   are already defined on super pom."

So, I deleted all my dependencies and added them back, one by one until I got it to compile.  All I needed was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
    <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I even deleted all the dependencies for the FlexMojos plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
    <configuration>
            <targetPlayer>${flash.player.version}</targetPlayer>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This worked for me, producing the SWC I need and I hope it helps someone else, too!